# Is any part of this .net async api method not async

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, api

I using a API http://themoviedbapi.codeplex.com/ but if I call for example 7 instances of this method it takes 2-3 sek to run and in the meantime my app is locked. So is any part this method implemented wrongly so it aint run async?

```
#region GetMovieInfoAsyncMethods
private delegate void GetMovieInfoDelegate(int id, object userState, AsyncOperation asyncOp);

public void GetMovieInfoAsync(int id)
{
    GetMovieInfoAsync(id, null);
}

public void GetMovieInfoAsync(int id, object userState)
{
    AsyncOperation asyncOp = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
    GetMovieInfoDelegate worker = new GetMovieInfoDelegate(GetMovieInfoWorker);
    worker.BeginInvoke(id, userState, asyncOp, null, null);
}

private void GetMovieInfoWorker(int id, object userState, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
{
    Exception exception = null;
    TmdbMovie movie = null;
    try
    {
        movie = GetMovieInfo(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exception = ex;
    }
    ImdbMovieInfoCompletedEventArgs args = new ImdbMovieInfoCompletedEventArgs(movie, exception, false, userState);
    asyncOp.PostOperationCompleted(
        delegate(object e) { OnGetMovieInfoCompleted((ImdbMovieInfoCompletedEventArgs)e); },
        args);
}

protected virtual void OnGetMovieInfoCompleted(ImdbMovieInfoCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (GetMovieInfoCompleted != null)
        GetMovieInfoCompleted(this, e);
}
#endregion
```

Comment: While the code is using delegates to execute asynchronously, it looks like it still all runs on the UI thread (Invoking delegates only runs the message pump, it doesn't thread it), and network operations are blocking. So you probably need to run the methods that call the network in another thread.

Comment: @Andrew Are you sure that's the case for `BeginInvoke` as well as `Invoke`?  I thought `BeginInvoke` used the threadpool?  I never use it tbh, I use `BackgroundWorker` or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` (and soon the parallel task stuff in .NET 4.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should put some `Debug.Write()`-style tracing in there so you can see where things are starting and stopping.

My initial guess from your sourcecode posting is that when `GetMovieInfoCompleted` is fired, something that subscribes to it takes a long time to run (e.g. updating many UI components).

What you're doing in your code sample looks okay at first glance because you're calling `Control.BeginInvoke()` which wouldn't block.  The whole point of `BeginInvoke` as opposed to `Invoke` is it's non-blocking.

**UPDATE**:
You had an interesting comment about `BeginInvoke` still blocking the UI thread.  I wasn't aware of that because I don't use it.  Instead, consider using one of the following:

- The `BackgroundWorker` component.
- `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` (although that'll require more cross-thread marshalling on your part that `BackgroundWorker` would do for you).
- If you're on .NET 4.0, look at the Parallel Task Library.

Comment: Someone on IRC said " you're invoking the delegate asyncronious, but if you call it directly on the user thread, it'll still be blocking"

Comment: Hmm I don't think so - you're calling `Control.BeginInvoke()` which wouldn't block.  The whole point of `BeginInvoke` as opposed to `Invoke` is it's non-blocking.

Comment: Where should I use the BackgroundWorker, remember this is not my API, Iam just using it :) but I can recompile it, but I have just never made my own async so this is black magic to me

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` is a component you drop on your form that deals with the async stuff for you.  The API you are calling will be a blocking call, so the idea is that you call it on a different thread so that your UI isn't blocked and is still responsive.  The MSDN docs for `BackgroundWorker` are pretty good.

Comment: So should I somehow call the GetMovieInfoWorker in the a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  In fact, the `GetMovieInfoWorker` method would probably be called from the `BackgroundWorker_DoWork()` method (which is in turn called when you call `backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()`).

Comment: So I create those workerthreads (When I learned to create the workerthread) and remove GetMovieInfoDelegate worker = new GetMovieInfoDelegate(GetMovieInfoWorker);
    worker.BeginInvoke(id, userState, asyncOp, null, null); and call that instead

Comment: You don't need any delegate at all.  You write a method that returns the value from the web service call.  You then call that method from `backgroundWorker_DoWork()`, and put the return value from it in the `Result` property.  I think you need to read up on the `BackgroundWorker`.